# Proving that $+$ distributes over $\min^{*}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am not getting how to solve this question.

> The question defines a function as $\min^{*}(x,y) = -\ln(e^{-x} + e^{-y})$ and asks to prove that $\min^*$ has an identity element and that $+$ distributes over $\min^*$, thus proving that $(\Bbb{R}\:\cup\: \{\infty\},\min^*,+)$ is a commutative semi-ring.

I was able to prove that $\infty$ is an identity element. But if I assume the distributivity of addition over $\min^*$, I arrive at(assuming $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}\:\cup\: \{\infty\}$
$$-\ln(e^{-a}+e^{-(b+c)})=-\ln(e^{-a}+e^{-b})-\ln(e^{-a}+e^{-c})$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{-a}+e^{-(b+c)}=(e^{-a}+e^{-b})(e^{-a}+e^{-c})$$
$$\Rightarrow e^{-a}+e^{-(b+c)}=e^{-2a} + e^{-(b+c)} + e^{-(a+c)} + e^{-(b+a)} $$
$$\Rightarrow e^{-a} + e^{-b} + e^{-c} = 1$$

which is not something we're looking for. I don't get where I went wrong. Perhaps in my calculations, but I don't see it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think what you need to prove is that $x+\min^*(y,z)=\min^*(x+y,x+z)$.

Comment: Really???. what I thought by distribution was for example if we have two binary operators $.$ and $+$ and if we want to define them in their functional analogs then we might as well write $a.b = .(a,b)$ where $.() $ is just a fancy function. So the distribution of addition over multiplication can be written as $$a.(b+c) = a.b + a.c$$$$\Rightarrow .(a,b+c) = .(a,b) + .(a,c)$$. Isn't the case similar here if we replace $.$ by $min^*$ ?

Comment: No, you have $+$ as the "multiplication" and $\min^*$ as the "addition" of the semi-ring.

Comment: otherwise, you would want to prove that $\min^*$ distributes over $+$, which I suppose it isn't the case.